# Xcode 4.2 keeps stretching my launch image

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, launchimage

Whenever I create a launch image .png file and try to implement it in my application xcode 4.2 distorts the image, skewing it horizontally. 
I've tried resizing it several times in photoshop, but no matter what size the image is it's still stretched. 
Does anyone know how to solve this issue, I know you can replace the launch image with a viewController in xcode 6, which may have to be the sollution.

Comment: You are aware that you cannot submit a app build with Xcode 4.2 to the App Store. Also you can use an assets catalogue to set the launch images.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 4.2 is totally obsolete. We are about to end the beta cycle for Xcode 7.

Additionally, a lot of changes happened to launch screens to comply with all the new screen sizes. And it's handled in Xcode 6, so **consider to update Xcode**.